# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

i check every thing many times but still i got this message

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE location (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, location_setting TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, city_name TEXT NOT NULL, coord_lat REAL NOT NULL, coord_long REAL NOT NULL,  );
```

---

```
final String SQL_CREATE_WEATHER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +

            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +

            // the ID of the location entry associated with this weather data
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +

            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP + " REAL NOT NULL, " +

            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_HUMIDITY + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_PRESSURE + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WIND_SPEED + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DEGREES + " REAL NOT NULL, " +

            // Set up the location column as a foreign key to location table.
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY + ") REFERENCES " +
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID + "), " +

            // To assure the application have just one weather entry per day
            // per location, it's created a UNIQUE constraint with REPLACE strategy
            " UNIQUE (" + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ", " +
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE );";

    final String SQL_CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME +" (" +
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING +" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT + " REAL NOT NULL, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG+ " REAL NOT NULL, "+" );";


    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE);


    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_WEATHER_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its typo, check your last line

```
WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG+ " REAL NOT NULL, "+" );";
```

remove `,` from end after `NOT NULL`, it should be like

```
WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG+ " REAL NOT NULL "+" );";
```

Answer (score 0):

***its showing message of syntext error in create table query. Because you have added  extra  `,(coma)` in last field of table.
so,remove `,(coma)` from `SQL_CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE` just like below & try again***

---

```
final String SQL_CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME +" (" +
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING +" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT + " REAL NOT NULL, "+
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG+ " REAL NOT NULL "+" );";
```